# Four-Leaved Rose is an Affine Variety

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, parametric, affine-geometry

I need to prove that the curve defined by the polar equation $r=\sin(2\theta)$ is the affine variety $\textbf{V}((x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2)$. First I showed that any point on the curve defined by $r=\sin(2\theta)$ is in the affine variety by simple algebra.

The converse seems to be similar, but the book says to be careful since $r$ can be negative in $r=\sin(2\theta)$. I've looked over my solution and can't see why that might complicate things. Here's what I did:

Let $(x,y)\in \textbf{V}((x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2)$. Then

\begin{align*}
&(x^2+y^2)^3-4x^2y^2=0\\
&\Rightarrow (r^2)^3-4(r^2\cos^2(\theta))(r^2\sin^2(\theta))=0\\
&\Rightarrow r^6-r^4(2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^2=0\\
&\Rightarrow r^2-\sin(2\theta)=0\\
&\Rightarrow r=\sin(2\theta)
\end{align*}

Is what I did valid, or did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: You missed a square. You should conclude with $r^2 = (\sin(2\theta))^2$. But this is not equivalent to $r = \sin(2\theta)$. Since $r$ is always nonnegative, the defining equation should be something like $r = \lvert \sin(2\theta)\rvert$ (otherwise, there won't be any solutions for $\pi>\theta>\frac{\pi}2$).

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=r+%3D+sin(2theta)) plots the whole four-leaved rose for $r=\sin(2\theta)$. It is a big mystery to me, how there can be any solutions of $r=\sin(2\theta)$ for $\frac{\pi}2 < \theta < \pi$ (which somehow corresponds to the lower right leaf)!

Comment: @user218931 $r$ is not always nonnegative: when $r<0$ for a given $\theta$, we get the same point corresponding to $|r|$ and $\theta + \pi$.

Comment: I don't understand this: in polar coordinates $r$ is always nonnegative. As I understand it, the solution to the equation $r=\sin(2\theta)$ is the set $\{(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)\,|\, r>0, 0\le \theta<2\pi, r=\sin(2\theta)\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$. So why does the case $r<0$ for some $\theta$ correspond to the point $\lvert r\rvert$ and $\theta+\pi$? This doesn't seem to follow from the equation $r=\sin(2\theta)$…

Comment: @user218931 It makes perfect sense to me: for instance to get from the origin to the point $(r, \theta) = (-1, \pi/4)$, I point myself at an angle of $\pi/4$ and then move 1 unit backward, which is the same as the point $(1, 5\pi/4)$.  I don't know why you insist that $r$ is always non-negative: it visibly isn't according to the plot you linked.  There are two solutions to $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$, a positive one, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and a negative one, $r = -\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.  See Ch. 11 of Stewart's Calculus for further confirmation.

Comment: @SpamIAm thank you for your explanation. The reason I insisted that $r$ be always non-negative is that it is clearly redundant to allow for negative $r$ (and this is the first time I have see this). Without knowing about this convention, I think I have every right to be confused. So,  thanks a lot for clearing this up for me!